# Replace some characters

Tags: php, replace, arabic

I would like to replace some special characters in a text by blank thing:

```
<?php
$ar = ' بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ ';
echo str_replace('/[\u064b-\u0653]/g','', $ar);
echo '<br />';
?>
```

The sentence is not replace, is there any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `preg_replace` to use regex.

Use the "u" modifier to enable unicode support, there is no /g modifier afaik...

```
<?php
$ar = ' بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ ';
echo preg_replace('/[\\x{064b}-\\x{0653}]/u','', $ar);
echo '<br />';
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php:

> u (PCRE_UTF8)
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl.
>   Pattern and subject strings are treated as
>   UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix
>   and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern and the
>   subject is checked since PHP 4.3.5. An invalid subject will cause the
>   preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an
>   error of level E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are
>   regarded as invalid since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28);
>   formerly those have been regarded as valid UTF-8.

Comment: this is what I found through my search

Comment: You're using `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`. I updated the answer.

Comment: I've got an error: PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \\L, \\l, \\N{name}, \\U, or \\u at offset 2 in replace_word.php on line 10

Comment: use \\ to escape the unicode sequence >> `preg_replace('/[\\u064b-\\u0653]/u','', $ar);`

Comment: still the same error, I've found this one: http://www.unicodemap.org/range/12/Arabic/

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Seems like PHP doesn't support \u notation but \x{...} notation >> echo preg_replace('/[\\x{064b}-\\x{0653}]/u','', $ar);

Comment: yeah, that's what I used, if I would like to add these 2 ranges as well 06D6-06ED and 060d-0619 how can I edit your code to include 3 ranges?

Comment: Just add them in the character class like this: `preg_replace('/[\\x{060d}-\\x{0619}\\x{064b}-\\x{0653}\\x{06D6}-\\x{06ED}]/u','', $ar);`

Comment: I found this one as well, and it's pretty nice: `preg_replace('/[^\p{Arabic}\da-z-]/ui', '', $ar);` the problem is it replaces spaces as well

Comment: Please either update your question or better ask another one.. it's nice you found something that helps with your current situation but it has actually nothing to do with your original question :)

Comment: if you try the regex, it works, it related to my question, but in different way

Comment: and to help others, this is a good unicode converter https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter, thanks Hirnhamster for ur assistance